# Validating Json in Dart JsonSerializable and Freezed

Tags: json, dart, freezed, json-serializable

I'm using Freezed to create data classes, and to de-serialized them from a json (with the integration with JsonSerializable).
But sometimes the json are incomplete, and the `fromJson` method do not validate the json. So it throws a `_TypeError` error that I cannot catch.

There is a way to automatically validate the json?
I could use Json schema to manually validate it, but want to know if there is an automatic way first.

Comment: But why the JSON is incomplete in the first place?

Comment: It depends on the project.
This specific time is because I receive the input from a socket, and it is not always perfect.
That part is beyond my control.

Comment: Okay, you can use try and catch blocks and you can handle the failure in the exception block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a string can be json.decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112618/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-can-be-json-decode)

Comment: @OMiShah You are correct. It does work! Thanks a lot!
It didn't work for me before because I tried to get the error in a unit test. And throws a `_TypeError`, try to test it with `throwsA(throwsA(TypeError))`. Assumed that work the same in runtime.

The correct way to test it in `throwsA(const TypeMatcher<TypeError>())`.

Answer (score 0):

@OMi Shah helped me with his comments.

My problem was I was using making a unit tests where a parsing fails with a json with a wrong schema. But I was testing in wrong.

I searched online, and read that only exceptions can be catch, no error, and this was a weird type of error `_TypeError`.
That was wrong, you can actually catch errors with try and catch.

And this is the way of unit test it:

```
expect(
  () => FreezedClass.fromJson({"": ""}),
  throwsA(const TypeMatcher<TypeError>())
);
```

Thanks a lot.